# Paypal with express checkout to get BillingAgreementID

Tags: asp.net, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

I am working with the paypal using express checkout to get a billing agreement id.

I was following this guide:

https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/how-authorize-and-run-reference-transaction-express-checkout

In the first step when i do "SetExpressCheckout":
The following is the code

```
public string SetExpressCheckout(string Amount)
    {
        string returnURL = "http://localhost:50325/ReviewOrder.aspx" + "?amount=" + Amount + "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD";
        string cancelURL = returnURL.Replace("ReviewOrder", "ExpCheckOut");
        string strCredentials = "USER=" + strUsername + "&PWD=" + strPassword + "&SIGNATURE=" + strSignature;
        string strNVP = strCredentials;
        strNVP += "&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=AUTHORIZATION&&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=25" + "&L_BILLINGTYPE0=MerchantInitiatedBilling" + "&RETURNURL=" + returnURL;
        strNVP += "&CANCELURL=" + cancelURL;
        strNVP += "&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout&VERSION=" + strAPIVersion + "&DESC=test EC payment" +"&NOSHIPPING=0" ;
        //Create web request and web response objects, make sure you using the correct server (sandbox/live)
        HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strNVPSandboxServer);
        //Set WebRequest Properties
        wrWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        // write the form values into the request message
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(wrWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(strNVP);
        requestWriter.Close();
        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(wrWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        // and read the response
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        return responseData;
    }
```

The response is:

```
    TOKEN=EC-09082530FY878870B&
    TIMESTAMP=2013-03-25T00:45:56Z&
    CORRELATIONID=3d33037174d55&
    ACK=SuccessWithWarning&
    VERSION=86&
    BUILD=5479129&
    L_ERRORCODE0=11452&
    L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Merchant not enabled for reference transactions&
    L_LONGMESSAGE0=Merchant not enabled for reference transactions&
    L_SEVERITYCODE0=Warning
```

How to to get a BillingAgreeentd in Step 3:

Code for step 3 is:

```
public string GetBillingAgreementID()
    {
        string returnURL = "http://localhost:50325/ReviewOrder.aspx" + "?amount=" + Amount + "¤cy=USD";
        string cancelURL = returnURL.Replace("ReviewOrder", "ExpCheckOut");
        string strCredentials = "USER=" + strUsername + "&PWD=" + strPassword + "&SIGNATURE=" + strSignature;
        string strNVP = strCredentials;
        strNVP += "&RETURNURL=" + returnURL;
        strNVP += "&CANCELURL=" + cancelURL;
        strNVP += "&METHOD=CreateBillingAgreement&VERSION=" + strAPIVersion + "&TOKEN=" + Session["Token"];
        //Create web request and web response objects, make sure you using the correct server (sandbox/live)
        HttpWebRequest wrWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strNVPSandboxServer);
        //Set WebRequest Properties
        wrWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        // write the form values into the request message
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(wrWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(strNVP);
        requestWriter.Close();
        // Get the response.
        HttpWebResponse hwrWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)wrWebRequest.GetResponse();
        StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(wrWebRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        // and read the response
        string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
        responseReader.Close();
        return responseData;
    }
```

Response is:

```
 TIMESTAMP=2013-03-25T00:51:34Z&
 CORRELATIONID=854e6beed1e82&
 ACK=Failure&
 VERSION=86&
 BUILD=5479129&
 L_ERRORCODE0=11455&
 L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Buyer did not accept billing agreement&
 L_LONGMESSAGE0=Buyer did not accept billing agreement&
 L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error
```

How to get a BillingAgreemntId?
Is that because of "L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Merchant not enabled for reference transactions" this message from "SetExpressCheckout" am i not able to get BillingAgreementID?

Please help me on this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to contact PayPal and request this to be enabled on the account, if this is for a live account.  If you are needing it enabled on the sandbox, you would need to contact PayPal MTS and have this enabled on your sandbox account.